# Rename duplicate records in R

Tags: r

I'd like to rename duplicate categories in column "Product" (data$Product) based on the order of its occurrence. Below is data frame:

```
data <- data.frame(Product=c("1123Tr","5467Yr","15-f020WM","15-f020WM","15-f020WM","15-k153cl","17-f222nr","17-f222nr"),
               Platform=c("caribian","flare","tease","brill","kittl","moui","mouner","fourt"),
               Value = c(200,500,550,456,678,765,34,33))
```

Below is table - how the data.frame "data" looks like:

```
   Product    Platform    Value
   1123Tr     caribian    200
   5467Yr     flare       500
15-f020WM     tease       550
15-f020WM     brill       456
15-f020WM     kittl       678
15-k153cl     moui        765
17-f222nr     mouner       34
17-f222nr     fourt        33
```

And below is desired output:

```
    Product        Platform    Value
    1123Tr         caribian    200
    5467Yr         flare       500
 15-f020WM(D1)     tease       550
 15-f020WM(D2)     brill       456
 15-f020WM(D3)     kittl       678
 15-k153cl         moui        765
 17-f222nr(D1)     mouner       34
 17-f222nr(D2)     fourt        33
```

Could anyone give me some hint or advice on how to do that please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16646446/renaming-duplicate-strings-in-r?rq=1)

Comment: You could make the duplicate element unique with `make.unique`. ie. `data$Product <- with(data, make.unique(as.character(Product)))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is very close to the `make.unique` of akrun.

`ave` will do this sort of thing:

```
> ave(as.character(data$Product), data$Product, FUN=function(x) if (length(x)>1) paste0(x[1], '(', seq_along(x), ')') else x[1])
[1] "1123Tr"       "5467Yr"       "15-f020WM(1)" "15-f020WM(2)" "15-f020WM(3)" "15-k153cl"    "17-f222nr(1)" "17-f222nr(2)"
```

Comment: Thank you very much for great solution Matthew. Thanks a lot Akrun too.